# Unexpected keyword argument 'ragged' in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Trying to run a trained keras model with the following python code:

```py
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from keras.models import load_model

from imutils.video import VideoStream
from threading import Thread
import numpy as np
import imutils
import time
import cv2
import os

MODEL_PATH = "/home/pi/Documents/converted_keras/keras_model.h5"

print("[info] loading model..")
model = load_model(MODEL_PATH)


print("[info] starting vid stream..")
vs = VideoStream(usePiCamera=True).start()
time.sleep(2.0)

while True:
    frame = vs.Read()
    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=400)

    image = cv2.resize(frame, (28, 28))
    image = image.astype("float") / 255.0
    image = img_to_array(image)
    image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)
    (fuel, redBall, whiteBall, none) = model.predict(image)[0]
    label = "none"
    proba = none

    if fuel > none and fuel > redBall and fuel > whiteBall:
        label = "Fuel"
        proba = fuel
    elif redBall > none and redBall > fuel and redBall > whiteBall:
        label = "Red Ball"
        proba = redBall
    elif whiteBall > none and whiteBall > redBall and whiteBall > fuel:
        label = "white ball"
        proba = whiteBall
    else:
        label = "none"
        proba = none

    label = "{}:{:.2f%}".format(label, proba * 100)
    frame = cv2.putText(frame, label, (10, 25),
                        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (0, 255, 0), 2)
    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    if key == ord("q"):
        break

print("[info] cleaning up..")
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
vs.stop()
```

When I run it with python3, I get the following error:
`TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ragged'`

What's causing the error, and how do I get around it?

Versions:
Keras v2.3.1
tensorflow v1.13.1

Edit to add:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Documents/converted_keras/keras-script.py", line 18, in <module>
    model = load_model(MODEL_PATH)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/saving.py", line 492, in load_wrapper
    return load_function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/saving.py", line 584, in load_model
    model = _deserialize_model(h5dict, custom_objects, compile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/saving.py", line 274, in _deserialize_model
    model = model_from_config(model_config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/saving.py", line 627, in model_from_config
    return deserialize(config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/layers/__init__.py", line 168, in deserialize
    printable_module_name='layer')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/generic_utils.py", line 147, in deserialize_keras_object
    list(custom_objects.items())))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/sequential.py", line 301, in from_config
    custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/layers/__init__.py", line 168, in deserialize
    printable_module_name='layer')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/generic_utils.py", line 147, in deserialize_keras_object
    list(custom_objects.items())))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/sequential.py", line 301, in from_config
    custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/layers/__init__.py", line 168, in deserialize
    printable_module_name='layer')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/generic_utils.py", line 147, in deserialize_keras_object
    list(custom_objects.items())))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/network.py", line 1056, in from_config
    process_layer(layer_data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/network.py", line 1042, in process_layer
    custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/layers/__init__.py", line 168, in deserialize
    printable_module_name='layer')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/generic_utils.py", line 149, in deserialize_keras_object
    return cls.from_config(config['config'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1179, in from_config
    return cls(**config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ragged'
```

[h5 file link (google drive)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-8ADI40ujjmcLpv-Shn9b5qhvIZNqYcn/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please add your full error stack trace, along with part of code where you are getting error.

Comment: @VivekMehta I have added the full code and the error trace, I think this is what you asked for? Not that sure, sorry.

Comment: `"/home/pi/Documents/converted_keras/keras_model.h5"` is this the full path? Try giving it the absolute path.

Comment: @daudnadeem Yes, that's the absolute path to it.

Comment: Thanks for adding the full code and stack trace. It looks like something in generic_utils is being called with an __init__( ragged='something') but not sure why that would happen.

Comment: @zxsq can you give me a sample h5 file, or a link to one, so I can reproduce?

Comment: [link to the h5 file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-8ADI40ujjmcLpv-Shn9b5qhvIZNqYcn/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @zxsq seems like your issue is in your h5 file. I found 'ragged' in the h5, and deleted that key:value, after which I get `OSError: Unable to open file (file signature not found)` error. Possible corrupted h5 file?

Comment: @daudnadeem hmm, not sure. I made it with teachable machine, so I'll give it a go making another one but, I don't think it would be that.

Comment: How did you produce that model file? With which keras version?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro It was exported from [teachable machine](https://teachablemachine.withgoogle.com/) as keras

Answer (score 68, accepted):

So I tried link above which you have mentioned [teachable machine](https://teachablemachine.withgoogle.com/)
As it turns out model you have exported is from `tensorflow.keras` and not directly from `keras` API. These two are different. So while loading it might be using *tf.ragged* tensors that might not be compatible with keras API.

Soulution to your issue:
Don't import keras directly as your model is saved with Tensorflow's keras high level api. Change all your imports to `tensorflow.keras`

Change:

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from keras.models import load_model
```

to this:

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
```

It will solve your issue.

**EDIT :**
All of your imports, either should be from `Keras` or `tensorflow.keras`. Although being same API few things are different which creates these kind of issues. Also for `tensorflow` backend `tf.keras` is preferred, because [Keras 2.3.0](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/releases/tag/2.3.0) is last major release which will support backends other than tensorflow.

> This release brings the API in sync with the [tf.keras](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras) API as of TensorFlow 2.0. However note that it does not support most TensorFlow 2.0 features, in particular eager execution. If you need these features, use [tf.keras](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras).
>   This is also the last major release of multi-backend Keras. Going forward, we recommend that users consider switching their Keras code to [tf.keras](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras) in TensorFlow 2.0.

Comment: This fixed my issue. Thank you so much :)

Comment: I just change `import keras` by `import tensorflow.keras as keras`, and it worked! Thank you.

Comment: I encountered the same problem. However, I can't use `tf.keras` because I'm trying to run keras with a different backend. I trained & saved my model using `tf 2.2.0` & `keras 2.3.0-tf`, and trying to run it on `keras 2.2.4`, backend `PlaidML`. Any possible solution? Or just theoretically impossible?

Answer (score 2):

Like @Vivek Mehta said,
first change load_model from `keras` to `tensorflow.keras`  i.e

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
```

But even then if the model loading shows error like  `KeyError: 'sample_weight_mode'` then do the following

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model

model = load_model('model.h5', compile = False)
```