# Keras won't load json file

Tags: keras, deep-learning

I ran my code and saved saved my model using the following code:

```
model_json = model.to_json()
with open(inFilePath+".json", "w") as json_file:
    json_file.write(model_json)
modWeightsFilepath=inFilePath+".weights.hdf5"
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(modWeightsFilepath, monitor='val_accuracy', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, save_weights_only=True, mode='auto')
```

And then I wanted to load my model again to make predictions:

```
from keras.models import model_from_json
json_file = open('/home/models/final_model.json', 'r')
loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
json_file.close()
model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)
#load weights into new model
model.load_weights('/home/models/final_model.weights.hdf5')
print("Loaded model from disk")
```

But this gives me the following error:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ragged'
```

Full traceback:

[image]

And I don't quite know what's wrong. My Keras gpu version is 2.1.6-tf.

Edit:

In order to create the model I used:

```
import json
import numpy as np
from generator import DataGenerator
import tensorflow
KERAS_BACKEND=tensorflow
import keras
from keras.preprocessing import sequence
from keras.models import Sequential, Model
from keras import optimizers
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten, Input
from keras.layers import Conv1D, AveragePooling1D, MaxPooling1D
from keras.layers.merge import concatenate
from keras.optimizers import SGD
import os
import sys
from itertools import chain
#import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from functools import reduce
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping,ModelCheckpoint
from sklearn.utils import class_weight
```

And in order to load the model, I imported:
from keras.models import model_from_json

after which I got the error that I told you about. And then I changed it to:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import model_from_json
```

And the error persisted.

Comment: please post the full traceback

Comment: I just added the full traceback

Comment: this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58878421/unexpected-keyword-argument-ragged-in-keras  since I'm unsure where you got the model from.

Comment: Yes I've already tried that. It's not working.

Comment: What exactly did you try from the above question, and what code/imports did you use to produce the model? This is most likely a issue between mixing tf.keras and keras

Comment: I've put it up in my question @Dr. Snoopy. It was too long to be put here.

Comment: Did you train this model with a different (older) version of Keras?

Comment: No. The model was trained using the same version of Keras.

Comment: And what version of keras is that? 2.1.6-tf is the version of tf.keras

Comment: This is what I get when I say print(Keras.__version__)

Comment: That means you are using Keras 2.4.x which is now just a wrapper on top of tf.keras, so if you trained your model with a "real version" of keras, it won't work as it is being loaded with tf.keras. If you want to use classic keras, make sure not to use version 2.4.x

Comment: So you mean: import tensorflow as tf and then wherever I use keras.layers for example I change it to tf.keras.layers?

Comment: No, I did not say anything liken that. It is your choice if you use keras or tf.keras

Comment: No I mean if I am using keras 2.4.x the I should do what I just said above?